# "type or namespace could not be found" but assembly is referenced, and frameworks are all 4

Tags: c#, .net

I thought I'd share this as a question and answer to help out some other poor souls, plus someone may be able to tell me WHY this solution works.

So I have a .net 4 project that is dependent on another .net 4 library. The intellisense can see the class within the dependent assembly. All looks like a classic framework version mismatch error - except they are the same.

If I change the main project to .net45 then everything works (but I don't want to).

Looking at the dependencies of the child project I see that it has the following among the usual:

```
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions
System.Threading.Tasks
```

It seems that this is the problem, even though the error message doesn't make any reference to it.

If you NuGet: **Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async**
This fixes it by adding the references that were missing.

So the real question is why? I speculate that they've moved things around in the framework between 4 and 4.5, fine, but why is the error message so misleading?

Comment: What is the exact "type" (i.e. class, interface, struct, enum, or delegate type) or namespace that it did not recognize? You: _The intellisense can see the class_ What class is that?

Comment: (From Memory) The namespace it couldn't find was that of our custom class.  It's a random custom class that I was trying to use from inside another of our dll's. It's not inherited from anything interesting. I believe everything is defined within a dependency chain, and everything is .net 4. It is exactly the effect you get if you are trying to access an assembly built in a higher version of the framework.

Comment: I think it is hard for us to answer the _WHY_ from your answer below without more information. Maybe you could reduce this to a minimal example where the _type or namespace could not be found_ message comes in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you NuGet: **Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async**
This fixes it by adding the references that were missing. 
(but if anybody knows WHY the error is so misleading, that would be great)